# Redhat Fuse-Karaf refusing to inject jms ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-karaf, activemq-artemis, fuse

Fuse karaf fuse-karaf-7.11.1.fuse-7_11_1-00013-redhat-00003.

I am creating a simple bridge from servlet to ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.9 using the AMQP protocol. I managed to configure a JMS `ConectionFactory` and tested OK with the `jms:send` command. I wrote a JMS service which is responding to the POST from the servlet side, but is failing to create the Connection factory.

```
admin@root()> jms:connectionFactories
JMS Connection Factory
----------------------
jms/artemis
```

The Jms service code is:

```java
package com.mycompany.jms;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TemporaryQueue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.*;

import org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.service.Reference;
import org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.service.Service;
import org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.service.ServiceProperty;

import com.mycompany.JmsService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Service(classes = JmsService.class, properties = {
// Only necessary for Remote Services
@ServiceProperty(name = "service.exported.interfaces", values = "*") })
@Singleton
public class JmsService4Reals implements JmsService {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsService4Reals.class);


@Reference
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Override
public String sendMessage(String opeCod, String message) {
LOG.info(String.format("received: opeCod=%s, msg=%s", opeCod, message));
try {
    if(connectionFactory== null)
        return "Reference: no connectionFactory found";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        LOG.info("JMS Connection created=%s", connection);
        connection.start();


    } catch (JMSException e) {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.stop();
        return prepareErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
    }
} catch (JMSException e) {
    return prepareErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
}
}

private String prepareErrorResponse(String msg) {
return msg;
}

}
```

The servlet always reponds with

```
Reference: no connectionFactory found
```

I also tried with the JNDI lookup method with the same result.

```java
try {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    LOG.info("context=%s", context);
    connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/artemis");
    LOG.info("connectionFactory=%s", connectionFactory);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "no connectionFactory found on JNDI";
    }
```

I expect the jms/artem`your text`is to be injected on my `ConnectionFactory`, but never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The actual exception you get when calling `context.lookup()` is:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: \
    Need to specify class name in environment or system property, \
    or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  \
    java.naming.factory.initial
```

That's how JNDI works and you need special preparation to use it in OSGi (and Fuse Karaf is OSGi runtime based on Apache Karaf).

You have to install `jndi` feature first. Then your exception will be:

```
javax.naming.NotContextException: jms/artemis
```

However it's almost everything you need. `jndi` feature gives you several commands, like this one:

```
karaf@root()> jndi:names
JNDI Name                │ Class Name
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
osgi:service/jms/artemis │ org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
osgi:service/jndi        │ org.apache.karaf.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl
```

If you now use `osgi:service/jms/artemis` instead of just `jms/artemis`, you get proper connection factory. I got this in logs:

```
2023-01-02 09:45:53,412 INFO  {XNIO-2 task-1} [grgr.test.Activator7$1.doGet()] \
(Activator7.java:65) : connectionFactory=ActiveMQConnectionFactory [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl \
[initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) \
?port=61616&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], \
clientID=null, consumerWindowSize = 1048576, \
dupsOKBatchSize=1048576, transactionBatchSize=1048576, readOnly=falseEnableSharedClientID=false]
```

You can find more examples of persistence usage in Fuse Karaf [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts).

A developer documentation is [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/tree/7.x.redhat-7-11-x/persistence/manual/src/main/asciidoc).